# Spring Boot: I am interested how an actual DispatcherServlet/Front Controller implementation looks like in code

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlets, controller

I am trying to go a bit more deeper in how a dispatcher servlet is actually auto implemented by spring boot.I know and understand the dispatcher servlet schema and how it routes the request to the respective controllers and handlers so i do not need that.I would actually like to see an actual code implementation of a dispatcher servlet.Where can i see this?

Since java spring is based on the servlets technology, i know that a Servlet class (implements HttpServlet) has only 1 of each http protocol equivalent methods (doPost,doGet,doPut,doDelete) available in the service method.That means you can only do 1 doGet/doPost etc... per servlet.If you need more , you need to create another servlet.You can of course also create an if/else inside the doPost/doGet etc to have more options , but you basically can only have one.

How is this transposing to a front servlet that can route to different classes that have N get/post request methods?

I would appreciate some code of the actual implementation if possible, thank you!

UPDATE:Just found what i needed by searching for DisparcherServlet source code!

Comment: There is nothing auto-implemented. Spring Boot just uses the [`DispatcherServlet`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java) from Spring and auto-configures it. And as Spring is OpenSource you can just look at the code.

Comment: yep i just found the DispatcherServlet implementation by searching for its source code online.